# Відповідник до німецького фразеологізму

Tags: переклад, from-german

Цікавить відповідник до німецького фразеологізму:

> Was Hänschen nicht lernt, lernt Hans nimmermehr.

Його можна перекласти як:

> Того чого не вивчив маленький Гансик, вже не вивчить дорослий Ганс

Тобто, означає воно: "Якщо ми не навчилися чогось в дитинстві/молодості, то і коли будемо дорослими, ми цього не начимося".

Я переглядав [словник найуживаніших фразеологізмів](https://phoenicis.com.ua/slovnyk-naiuzhyvanishykh-frazeolohizmiv.html), але мені не вдалося знайти фразеологізму, який б влучно передавав значення. Чи взагалі існує такий в українській мові?

Comment: Наьблизшим хіба шчо пригадуьу _бережи честь змолоду_.

Comment: Найближче, що мені спадає на думку: _старого собаку новим трюкам не навчиш_ (можливо, воно російського походження, але радше [міжнародне](//google.com/search?q=you+can't+teach+an+old+dog+new+tricks)). Але це не зовсім те, робиться інший акцент. Німецький варіант мені подобається більше: там робиться акцент на тому, що треба вчитися змолоду (і це, по-моєму, правильно); а у варіанті про собаку — що старі нездатні до навчання (що, по-моєму, не зовсім правильно: чим старше людина, тим менш вона здібна до навчання, але ця здатність ніколи не падає до 0, тому не варто ставити на людині хрест).

Comment: У нас кажуть навпаки - *вік живи - вік учись*

Comment: привіт, час дієслова в німецькому варіянті — теперішній. нмд, більш точний переклад: "Чого малий Івасько не вивчить, того Іван й не вивчить й тим паче" :)

Comment: Шче згадав таке _шчо посїєш – те ꙇ пожнеш_. Але знов ж, воно не відтворює повністю нїмецького виразу.

Comment: Дякую, всім за ваші відповіді. Здається, що кожна з них зазлуговує уваги, і, залежно від контексту, може буди хорошим відповідником. Гадаю, що цих коментарів вже достатньо для хорошої відповіді.

Answer (score 4):

В українській мові є прямий відповідник німецького прислів'я:

> **Чого Івась не навчиться, того й Іван не буде вміти.**

Його [знаходимо](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=qsZIAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA117&dq=%D0%A7%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE+%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F,+%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE+%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi487bL0t3lAhWlw4sKHcvYAREQ6AEIPzAC#v=snippet&q=%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%86%D1%8F&f=false) у збірнику "Українські приказки, прислів'я, і таке інше" М. Номиса 1864 року:

[image]

Це ж прислів'я є у [томі 2](http://labs.lnu.edu.ua/folklore-studies/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2018/03/Etnografichnyj_zbirnyk_Tom_23_Lviv,1909_Haly%D1%81ko-ruski_narodni_prypovidky_tom02_vyp01.pdf) збірника "Галицько-руські народні приповідки" Івана Франка 1907 року (стор. 218)

[image]

Там само:

[image]

У [пізніших публікаціях](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=vE8NAQAAMAAJ&dq=%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C) це прислів'я теж можна знайти, та й ґуґл видає безліч результатів ([наприклад](http://www.aphorism.org.ua/subrazd.php?page=454&pages_block=31&rid=2&sid=16)). Тому його можна і варто вживати.